# Re-requiring module that parent requires

Tags: node.js, express, require

I'm in the process of learning NodeJS (using Express), and came across something that struck me as odd.

In app.js i'm requiring a module (passport in this case), and then requiring a second module (passport-strats.js) which I developed. Inside of passports-strats I have to re-require passport even though it's already required in app.js.

This isn't the only example, I have some modules required in three files that are all tightly related. Is this standard or am I missing some crucial piece of structuring NodeJS applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you require the `passport` module once you should require it in `passport-strats.js` and export it from this module. In app.js you can use both modules just importing `passport-strats.js`. ie:

```
//passport-strats.js

var {passport} = require("./path");
//other code

module.exports = { passport, someVariableFromCurrentModel };


//In app.js

var {passport, someVariableFromCurrentModel} = require("./passport-strats");
```

Comment: That makes sense, but what if I have one module that needs to be used in a half dozen or so files? Is standard practice to require them each time? I'm mostly just wanting to make sure that i'm not missing something, chances are i'm overthinking it.

Comment: "but what if I have one module that needs to be used in a half dozen or so files?" This approach works too.

Comment: Is this something you'd recommend doing to improve performance, or is it more of a "this is how you'd do it if you wanted to for some reason" situation?

Comment: Require the same module in 20 diffents files represents the same effort to node like if it was just once because the first time you require it node cached that file and in the second attempt it return you the cached file. Frankly i don't ever hear about best practice for require a module in multiple files.

Comment: That works, the fact that it's not discussed much in general makes me feel better about it. For some reason I was thinking I was doing something horribly wrong. Thanks!